# Make parent height fit to the content height (CSS)

Tags: html, css

Can someone help me to understand how can I make the height (red border) fit to the content (green border)?

[image]

I am having trouble understanding which property to use, 
I am trying to get this result but I have not been successful

[image]

```css
div.items {
  position: fixed;
  top: 7.4cm;
  left: 1cm;
  width: 19.6cm;
  height: 4.5cm;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

div.item {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 19px;
}

div.cantidades {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0.1cm;
  width: 1.6cm;
}

div.descripcion {
  position: absolute;
  left: 1.9cm;
  width: 10.5cm;
}

div.precioUnitario {
  position: absolute;
  left: 12.4cm;
  width: 1.5cm;
}

div.ventas {
  position: absolute;
  left: 17.4cm;
  width: 2.2cm;
}

div.green {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="cantidades">2</div>
    <div class="descripcion">TM. MAIZ AMARILLO DE MUELLE DE CEPA HACIA BODEGAS DE ALMAPAC</div>
    <div class="precioUnitario">$1.60</div>
    <div class="ventas">$60</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="cantidades">2</div>
    <div class="descripcion">TM. MAIZ blanco</div>
    <div class="precioUnitario">$1.90</div>
    <div class="ventas">$6</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please also attach your HTML code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're looking for responsive layout then use `flex` always, I have also removed `few` unnecessary code from yours, because those are `contradicting` your requirement.

```css
div.items {
  top: 3.4cm;
  left: 1cm;
  width: 19.6cm;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

div.item {
  border: 0px solid red;
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

div.cantidades {
  left: 0.1cm;
  width: 1.6cm;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

div.descripcion {
  left: 1.9cm;
  width: 10.5cm;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

div.precioUnitario {
  left: 12.4cm;
  width: 1.5cm;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

div.ventas {
  border: 1px solid green;
  left: 17.4cm;
  width: 2.4cm;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Print Test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="items">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="cantidades">2</div>
      <div class="descripcion">TM. MAIZ AMARILLO DE MUELLE DE CEPA HACIA BODEGAS DE ALMAPAC TM. MAIZ AMARILLO DE MUELLE DE CEPA HACIA BODEGAS DE ALMAPAC</div>
      <div class="precioUnitario">$1.60</div>
      <div class="ventas">$60</div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <div class="cantidades">2</div>
      <div class="descripcion">TM. MAIZ blanco</div>
      <div class="precioUnitario">$1.90</div>
      <div class="ventas">$6</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: yes that is exactly what i want, but now the issue is the div with "venta" class did not draw like the picture I shared before

Comment: I removed border, you can add border for that class and make it work. Check it now I have added green border to the `ventas` class.

Comment: I mean the blank space between div. precioUnitario and div. ventas
or in other words, `left: 17.4cm;` property of div.ventas is not render

Comment: I feel this is what you looking for https://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/3cfhmpta/3/

Comment: this is a template to print an invoice, so I need to respect the div positions, that's why I need that the "left" property works properly [link](https://ibb.co/mvRrck1)

Comment: Yes! that was I looking for, should I need to add `position:absolute;` to each div?

Comment: got it the latest fiddle url will give you what you need, use `position:absolute` and `right:0;` only for that div and you will have that div in the last.

Comment: you can but I don't see why should you use for all divs,  use only for those which is in need, like you can just play around and may get a gist.

Comment: got it, Thank you.!